# Schedule Page to Menu

Tags: menus, pages, sub-menu, child-pages, scheduled-posts

Every week I tend to have 2-4 pages scheduled though I need to get them added to my menu as well.

The "Add New Top Level Pages to Menu" option won't work in my case though as the pages in question aren't top level. In odd cases they're subpages of subpages.

Does anyone know of any way to schedule pages to add to a menu with or without a plugin? I would try and code one in but it's a little too complicated for me.

I posted this exact question on the WordPress support forum and it's gone unanswered for too long, hoping for some answers here.

Thanks.

EDIT: Side question, is there a way to schedule an edit?

Comment: @DavidGard I don't think so...

Comment: Why don't you think so? The question reads as seemingly exactly the same. If that is not the case then you need to elaborate. Help us to help you...

Comment: The first part I understand and I can also get why you think your question is different because of the menu location and the event when the pages are added to the menu. But trust @David, the technique and code are almost the same.

Comment: I didn't understand your side question. What does it mean to schedule an edit? What would be edited and where is the source of the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this plugin will do what you want.

**Jamocreations Auto Submenu** https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-submenu/

Here is also a link to the author's site, http://jamocreations.com/en/artikelen/auto-submenu , where he discusses why he built the plugin and also two other plugins that also work similarly.  The advantage of the Jamocreations Auto Submenu plugin though is that if later you want to edit the menu using Wordpress Menu editor the entries are actually visible there so you can reorder them or whatever.

The plugin works based on selecting a parent page from the Wordpress page editor. If the parent page or parent sub-page has been added to the Wordpress menu, then its child pages will automatically be added as well.